# Compile TPM-Emulator error

Tags: makefile, tpm

just trying to compile [TPM-Emulator](https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator) under Ubuntu 32 bit.
Setting `export ARCH=i386`, having

```
tomasz@tomasz-VirtualBox:~/Git$ find /usr/include -name socket.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h
/usr/include/linux/socket.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/socket.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h
```

I get similiar errors

```
[ 98%] Generating linux/tpmd_dev.ko
/home/tomasz/Git/tpm-emulator/build/tpmd_dev/linux/tpmd_dev.c: In function ‘tpmd_handle_command’:
/home/tomasz/Git/tpm-emulator/build/tpmd_dev/linux/tpmd_dev.c:111:6: error: ‘struct msghdr’ has no member named ‘msg_iov’
   msg.msg_iov = &iov;
      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** There is a TPM 2.0 compliant TPM Simulator by IBM, [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmswtpm2/)

In the git repo, that you linked a [user](https://github.com/Aorimn/tpm-emulator/commit/0343c02f040e133697c9301b21668da364f81ecc) made a pull request for a fix to your problem. This worked for me (there are some whitespace fixes that I didn't use. If the patch makes problems just make the changes by hand).

```
--- tpmd_dev.c  2016-01-10 16:36:21.964858503 +0100
+++ tpmd_dev.c  2016-01-10 16:37:09.377204027 +0100
@@ -25,6 +25,8 @@
 #include <linux/net.h>
 #include <linux/un.h>

+#include <linux/version.h>
+
 #include "config.h"

 #define TPM_DEVICE_MINOR  224
@@ -81,7 +83,7 @@
   }
   addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
   strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_name, sizeof(addr.sun_path));
-  res = tpmd_sock->ops->connect(tpmd_sock, 
+  res = tpmd_sock->ops->connect(tpmd_sock,
     (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un), 0);
   if (res != 0) {
     error("sock_connect() failed: %d\n", res);
@@ -108,9 +110,17 @@
   memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
   iov.iov_base = (void*)in;
   iov.iov_len = in_size;
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3,19,0)
   msg.msg_iov = &iov;
   msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
+#else
+  iov_iter_init(&msg.msg_iter, WRITE, &iov, 1, 1);
+#endif
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,1,0)
   res = sock_sendmsg(tpmd_sock, &msg, in_size);
+#else
+  res = sock_sendmsg(tpmd_sock, &msg);
+#endif
   if (res < 0) {
     error("sock_sendmsg() failed: %d\n", res);
     return res;
@@ -122,8 +132,12 @@
   memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
   iov.iov_base = (void*)tpm_response.data;
   iov.iov_len = tpm_response.size;
-  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
-  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3,19,0)
+   msg.msg_iov = &iov;
+   msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
+#else
+  iov_iter_init(&msg.msg_iter, WRITE, &iov, 1, 1);
+#endif
   oldmm = get_fs();
   set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
   res = sock_recvmsg(tpmd_sock, &msg, tpm_response.size, 0);
@@ -194,7 +208,7 @@
     kfree(tpm_response.data);
     tpm_response.data = NULL;
   }
-  if (tpmd_handle_command(buf, count) != 0) { 
+  if (tpmd_handle_command(buf, count) != 0) {
     count = -EILSEQ;
     tpm_response.data = NULL;
   }
@@ -241,8 +255,8 @@
 };

 static struct miscdevice tpm_dev = {
-  .minor      = TPM_DEVICE_MINOR, 
-  .name       = TPM_DEVICE_ID, 
+  .minor      = TPM_DEVICE_MINOR,
+  .name       = TPM_DEVICE_ID,
   .fops       = &fops,
 };
```